# Select-Object omitting output from Select-String powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I wrote a Powershell script that looks for a string (such as ERROR) in log files and grabs those lines and outputs those lines to a file, for simpler reading and such (the industry I'm in has VERY large log files), but I'm having an issue. Before, when the (relevant) part of the code looked like this:

```
Select-String -Path "$file" -Pattern "$string" -CaseSensitive | Out-File -filepath $filepath
```

It would output the file path, the line number, and then the actual line, making for a very cluttered file. Well I only needed the line and the line number, so I did this:

```
Select-String -Path "$file" -Pattern "$string" -CaseSensitive | Select-Object -Property LineNumber,Line | Out-File -filepath $filepath
```

Which would return lines looking like this:

```
978 2017-07-10 10:46:11,288 ERROR [Music...
```

That is the line number then the line, with the line only totaling 35 characters.
Before I piped `Select-String` to `Select-Object`, the script would output the whole line, but now with `Select-Object` it omits some output. I tried adding `-verbose` parameters to both `Select-String` and `Select-Object`, but that did nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
Select-String -Path "test.xml" -Pattern "ERROR" -CaseSensitive | ft -Property LineNumber,Line -Wrap  | Out-File -FilePath c:\out.txt
```

The reason for your problem is screen buffer length([increasing powershell screen buffer width](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/12/04/how-can-i-expand-the-width-of-the-windows-powershell-console/)) ,you can change it as well but the above snippet is simpler and effective

Comment: That's awesome! The screen buffer thing didn't occur to me and I will look into expanding it, but write now piping it into a table and wrapping the words works! Thanks!